# Is possible to make a REST Call to webscript from own Java Backed Webscript?

Tags: rest, alfresco

I'm doing a Java Backed Webscript to put in Alfresco and call it via REST. This Webscript must do a set of 3 operations (find a path, create a folder and upload a document).

I read about this and found similar examples to do this operations throw the native Alfresco API, with methods like getFileFolderService, getContentService, etc. of Repository or ServiceRegistry classes. All in Java, without javascript.

But I would rather use REST calls instead of Alfresco API inside my Webscript. I think that if already exists Webscripts to do these operacions, is easier call them than use Alfresco API methods to try to do it. And if the API changes in future versions, the REST calls would remain the same. But I'm new here and I don't know if I'm wrong.

In summary: to do these 3 operacions, one after another, in my backed webscript, what is better and why? Use native API methods or use REST calls to existing webscripts?

And if I try to do the second option, is possible to do this? Using HttpClient class and GetMethod/PostMethod for the REST calls inside my Java Webscript may be the best option for Rest calls?. Or this could give me problems? Because I use a Rest call to my backed webscript that do another rest calls to another webscripts.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing HTTP calls against the process you are already in is a very very bad idea in general. It is slower, much more complex and error-prone, hogs more resources (two threads), and in your case, you will even lose transaction safety. Just imagine the last call fails for some reason. Besides you will most likely have to handle security context propagation yourself. Use the native public API and it will be easy, safe and stable.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's bad practice to do it like this. In a lot of Alfresco versions the default services didn't change a bit. Even when they changed they still had deprecated methods.

The rest api changed as well. If you want to make an upgrade proof system I guess it's better to stick with the Webservices (which didn't change since version 2.x) or go with CMIS.
But then it doesn't make sense to have your code within Alfresco, so putting it within an interface is better.

I'd personally just stick with the JavaScript API which didn't change a lot. Yes more functions were enabled within, but the default actions to search & CRUD remained the same.

You could even to a duo: Have your Java Backendscript do whatever fancy stuff and send the result to je JavaScript controller and do the default stuff.